# htaccess rewrite rules on Windows server 2008 & Apache not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am pulling my hair out with rewrite rules i try to implement for days now, since i have completely re-done a website, where OLD URL's must be now redirect to NEW URL's

(Remark: Running Apache on a Windows 2008R2)

OLD links always are:
www.domain.com/files/

NEW links are:
domain.com/_fileuploads/

a sample (OLD) URL would be
www.domain.com/files/Media/Statistics/Germany/services%202003-2012.pdf

I tried almost everything:

```
Redirect 301 /files/Media/Statistics/Germany/services%202003-2012.pdf$  http://domain.com/_fileuploads/entries/Statistics/services%202003-2012.pdf

RewriteRule ^/files/Media/Statistics/Germany/services%202003-2012\.pdf$ http://domain.com/_fileuploads/entries/Statistics/services%202003-2012.pdf [NC,R=301,L]

RedirectMatch 301 /files/Media/Statistics/Germany/services%202003-2012.pdf$ http://domain.com/_fileuploads/entries/Statistics/services%202003-2012.pdf
```

None of the above solutions works for me, i always get an 404 not found
Your wise input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use mod_rewrite only for this purpose and avoid mod_alias.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^files/Media/(.+)$ /_fileuploads/entries/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: was maybe a bad example of mine. My apologies. The NEW URL's structure is not exactly kept as the old ones. It can be that in some cases, the file is in a totally different location. What if /files/Media/xxxx.pdf is now in /_uploads/somedir/xxxx.pdf?

Comment: If new location is totally different then you can't have a generic rules like above and will have to write the specific ones like: `RewriteRule ^files/Media/(xxxx\.pdf)$ /_fileuploads/entries/$1 [L,NC,R=301]` Hope you get it going.

Comment: it won't work.. i get Internal Server Error. Overrides are allowed and set in apache config.

Comment: Can you tell me what error you;re seeing in Apache's `error.log`

Comment: it says: .htaccess: Option MultiViews not allowed here

Answer (score 0):

It was the issue, while copying URL's from the browser bar, that white spaces are filled with %20 to the text editor.

This solution actually did the trick for me, where %20 was replaced with [\ |%2520]:

```
RewriteRule 
^/files/Media/Statistics/Germany/services[\ |%2520]2003-2012\.pdf
"http://domain.com/_fileuploads/entries/Statistics/services 2003-2012.pdf"
```